# Disable vim-better-whitespace highlighting for nvim-ipy buffer

Tags: neovim, whitespace

I am using the [vim-better-whitespace plugin](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace) to highlight trailing whitespaces. For some buffers, I don't want this behavior and vim-better-whitespace usually provides an option to list the filetypes where it shouldn't apply.

However, I am also using [nvim-ipy](https://github.com/bfredl/nvim-ipy) to integrate with ipython and this plugin opens a new buffer for console output, where `filetype` is empty and `buftype` is set to `nofile`.

Is there any way to construct an `autocmd` to call `DisableWhitespace` once the respective ipython buffer is created?

Comment: I don't use any of these tools so that is just a random guess: It seems like an autocommand will not be possible since you can't determine to buffer type/filetype **but** if you open your new buffer with a mapping maybe you could try something like this: `nnoremap <key> <Plug>(IPy-Run) <bar>:DisableWhitespace<CR>`. This would create a mapping which would open the buffer and then call the command you're looking for. Once again this is just a guess I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: @statox I think the problem with this approach is that nvim-ipy doesn't focus the ipython buffer. So I would also have to add commands to move there etc....

Comment: Indeed that would make you create a whole wrapper for the plugin which is not the ideal solution. Have you tried to ask the author his opinion? Maybe the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bfredl/nvim-ipy/issues) would be a good place to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `BufFilePost` based on the buffer name being `[jupyter]`:

```
augroup filetype_jupyter
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufFilePost \[jupyter\]
  \ setlocal filetype=python |
  \ DisableWhitespace
augroup END
```

It also sets the `filetype` to Python.